# Donut Apex chart dynamic value for total in Vue js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, apexcharts

I wanted to set dynamic value for label and formatter function in donut apex chart. Below is my code

```
computed: {
  radialChartOptions: function () {
    return {
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          donut: {
            labels: {
              total: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                  return (val = "16:00 hrs");
                },
                label: "55:00 hrs",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
}
```

I have a watch function, inside the watch function I am setting the dynamic value. Here is the code

```
 this.radialChartOptions.plotOptions.pie.donut.labels.total = {
     formatter: function (val) {
         return (val = "29:00 hrs");
     },
 }
```

I want set dynamic value for formatter and i tried the above code and its not working. Please help on this.